# Creating view for adding nested resource in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, nomethoderror

I'm making a RoR app that has 3 resources, that are nested in this order: Projects -> Feeds -> XML_Fields.  Projects has_many Feeds, Feeds has_many XML_Fields.  My problem is that I am getting stuck on adding to the Show Feeds view the ability to add a new XML_Field.  My code is below:

```
<h2>Add an XML field:</h2>
<%= form_for ([@feed, @feed.xml_fields.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_area :tag %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Executing this returns a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'tag'`.  Tag is the name of the column in the xml_fields table I created.  My xml_fields_controller has this create method:

```
def create
@xml_field = Feed.find(params[:feed_id]).xml_fields.build(params[:xml_field])

respond_to do |format|
  if @xml_field.save
    format.html { redirect_to( :back, :notice => 'XML Field was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @xml_field, :status => :created, :location => [@xml_field.feed, @xml_field] }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @xml_field.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

And my routing file looks like this:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :feeds
end

resources :feeds do
  resources :xml_fields
end
```

Any suggestions to make this NoMethodError go away?  Thanks.

Comment: can you also add action "new" from controller? and what is the end of "undefined method 'tag'" it usually looks like: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: The full error is `undefined method 'tag' for #<XmlField:0x00000102b316d8>`.  I added a "new" action, but that didn't resolve anything.

Comment: so the error indicates that you have no tag field in table xml_fields but I know that you said it has this field... I don't know, maybe you have to restart server? (if you work on production and added this field later) or maybe you forgot to migrate?

Comment: Oh yikes, I feel silly now. I went and checked the DB table after your suggestion, and it turns out I named the field 'tags', not 'tag'.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

model XmlField doesn't have tag field in database ;)